# dplyr mutation with external data

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

We can easily mutate/summarise with respect to categorical means:

```
require(tidyverse)

iris %>% mutate_if(is.double, funs(. - mean(.))) %>% 
  gather(dimension, value, -Species) %>% 
  group_by(Species, dimension) %>% summarise(value = mean(value)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(dimension, value, fill=value)) + geom_bar(stat='identity') + 
  coord_flip() + facet_wrap(~ Species)
```

[image]

But consider the case where some other *baseline* (i.e. equivalent to but distinct from the *means* invoked in `mutate_if` above) are derived elsewhere, e.g.

```
baseline = data_frame(Sepal.Length=3, Sepal.Width=2, Petal.Length=2, Petal.Width=1)
```

To incorporate these, one base-r approach is simple, but inelegant:

```
for(i in 1:4) iris[,i] = iris[,i] - as.numeric(baseline[,i])
```

But I wonder if there's a nicer tidy way to incorporate `baseline` somehow within the pipeline - i.e. avoiding having to either alter `iris` itself or clone it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could loop on the relevant columns with `purrr::imap`

```
library(purrr)
iris %>% imap_dfc(~if(.y %in% names(baseline)) .x-baseline[[.y]] else .x)

# # A tibble: 150 x 5
#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>  <fctr>
#  1          2.1         1.5         -0.6        -0.8  setosa
#  2          1.9         1.0         -0.6        -0.8  setosa
#  3          1.7         1.2         -0.7        -0.8  setosa
#  4          1.6         1.1         -0.5        -0.8  setosa
#  5          2.0         1.6         -0.6        -0.8  setosa
#  6          2.4         1.9         -0.3        -0.6  setosa
#  7          1.6         1.4         -0.6        -0.7  setosa
#  8          2.0         1.4         -0.5        -0.8  setosa
#  9          1.4         0.9         -0.6        -0.8  setosa
# 10          1.9         1.1         -0.5        -0.9  setosa
```

For easy use in the future you could use the following function (written in base `R`), I generalized the function so you're not limited to substractions. `.baseline` can also be a list or named vector.

```
baseline_op <- function(.x, .baseline, .f = `-`, ...) {
  .x[names(.baseline)] <- lapply(names(.baseline),function(n, ...) .f(.x[[n]], .baseline[[n]], ...))
  .x
}

iris %>% baseline_op(baseline) %>% head
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1          2.1         1.5         -0.6        -0.8  setosa
# 2          1.9         1.0         -0.6        -0.8  setosa
# 3          1.7         1.2         -0.7        -0.8  setosa
# 4          1.6         1.1         -0.5        -0.8  setosa
# 5          2.0         1.6         -0.6        -0.8  setosa
# 6          2.4         1.9         -0.3        -0.6  setosa


iris %>% baseline_op(baseline, pmax, na.rm = TRUE) %>% head
# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1          5.1         3.5            2           1  setosa
# 2          4.9         3.0            2           1  setosa
# 3          4.7         3.2            2           1  setosa
# 4          4.6         3.1            2           1  setosa
# 5          5.0         3.6            2           1  setosa
# 6          5.4         3.9            2           1  setosa
```

Comment: `imap` solution is perfect, thanks. I wasn't aware `.y` offered col.names if not otherwise specified (if that's right?). I can't find reference in https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/index.html#section-map-family or https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/imap.html. I can see it demo'd in the `mtcars` example, but no explicit explanation.

Comment: `imap` is a wrapper around `map2`, with the second parameter being names or indices, maybe you were looking for this : https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/imap.html , see also the code from `imap`, it's 2 lines long :).

Comment: OK I misread `short hand for map2(x, names(x), ...) ..` as meaning _row-wise_! Thanks again.